# Regex Replace All causes misses

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm working on regex in order to replace some strings

```
public static String removeValuesByRegex(String input, Pattern pattern, String replaceWith){
 String result;

 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

 return result = matcher.replaceAll(replaceWith).trim();
}
```

Then in my test class im doing

```
String keywords = 'LLC|Corp|Corporation';
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)(?<= |^)\'|' + keyWords + '\'|(?= |$)');

String stringResult = UtilString.removeValuesByRegex('Corporation This Has a Name LLC AND CoRp ', pattern, '');
```

The output will come out as

> oration This Has a Name AND

What appears to be happening is the regex is finding Corp in Corporation and removing "Corp" which then messed up the the Corporation comparison, is this a regex update or can I not do this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries if you want to match whole words:

```
String keywords = '\\b(LLC|Corp|Corporation)\\b';
```

Note that the `\\` is necessary because source code must be escaped (this translates to a literal `\b` in the string, which is what the regular expression engine expects).

Comment: Thanks but how could I implement that with my current lookbehind/ahead pattern?

Comment: @EricSSH I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your implementation, it doesn't seem to be necessary? `\b` matches word boundaries, which is what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: The key words will be different based on what the metadata object says it should be so I believe I need to update my regex pattern to make it be an exact match https://regex101.com/r/w6mUEm/2/

Comment: I do see what your saying, just not sure why it isn't finding matches https://regex101.com/r/SBWNjK/1

Comment: @EricSSH Apex and regexp both use the backslash as an escape character. This means a regexp in Apex source code must have their backslashes escaped. On the site you linked, you would use just `\b` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually about to delete that comment above cause I just realized that